# Why can't I modify values of an array in a method?

Tags: ruby, arrays

In the code fragment below, the array `deck` should equal `[6,9,5,6,5,1,2]` since Ruby passes arrays by reference. After the method call, the values of deck does not change. Why is that?

```
def count_cut!(deck)
  s1, s2 = deck[0, deck.last], deck[deck.last..-2]
  deck = s2 + s1 + [deck.last]
end

deck = [5, 1, 6, 9, 5, 6, 2]
count_cut!(deck)
p deck
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.2-p180.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assigning to `deck` does not mutate the array that was passed in. It is treated like a local variable in the scope of the function definition. You can call `deck.replace` if you really want to mutate it.

Comment: Why does then deck.replace mutate deck if deck is a local variable in the scope of the method? or is assignment just a special case?

Comment: when you call `deck = s2 + s1 + [deck.last]` you create a new object. you can test it if you `puts deck.object_id` after assignment in the method and after `count_cut!(deck)`

Comment: Assignment is a special case, if you want to think of it that way. All values are passed by reference in Ruby, so any method that modifies the instance modifies it for everybody. But assignment changes that variable to point at a new instance.

Comment: I believe Ruby *passes references by value*.

Answer (score 5):

Do it the Ruby way: Instead of modifying the original array, return the modified array:

```
def count_cut(deck)
  s1, s2 = deck[0, deck.last], deck[deck.last..-2]
  s2 + s1 + [deck.last]
end
```

The caller then assigns the return value to `deck`:

```
deck = [5, 1, 6, 9, 5, 6, 2]
deck = count_cut(deck)
p deck
```

But consider encapsulating it all in a Deck class, especially if a deck has other behaviors:

```
class Deck

  def initialize(cards)
    @cards = cards
  end

  def count_cut!
    s1, s2 = @cards[0, @cards.last], @cards[@cards.last..-2]
    @cards = s2 + s1 + [@cards.last]
  end

end

deck = Deck.new [5, 1, 6, 9, 5, 6, 2]
deck.count_cut!
p deck
```

Answer (score 2):

The .+ method of Array gets you a *new* Array. Use .unshift to modify the original object.

```
deck = [1,2,3,4,5]
p deck.object_id #some_number
deck = [6] + deck
p deck.object_id #another_number
deck.unshift([7])
p deck.object_id #unchanged
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not modifying the array that the `deck` variable references, you're just assigning a new array to the local variable `deck`:

```
deck = s2 + s1 + [deck.last]
```

The above creates a new array whose contents are `s2 + s1 + [deck.last]`, this new array is then assigned to the local variable `deck`. The array that `deck` originally referenced is left unchanged. If you want to change the array, then you'd need something like this:

```
deck_last = deck.last
deck.clear
deck.push(*s2)
deck.push(*s1)
deck.push(deck_last)
```

or you'd lose the connection between the local variable `deck` and the non-local array that it references.